# Pass a variable from wxi to wixproj/define a variable in wixproj

Tags: variables, wix

I am trying to pass a defined value from the include file (wxi) to wixproj.

What I am trying to do is to do a copy action after build with the path containing the value of ***ReleaseCountry*** from wxi defined dynamically from my build automated process.

Below is what I'd imagine but not working.

In MyProject.wxi:

```
<?define ReleaseCountry="en-AU"?>
```

In MyProject.wixproj:

```
<Target Name="CopyToDeploy">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutputPath) $(OutputName).msi" DestinationFiles="..\Output\$(var.ReleaseCountry)\$(OutputName).msi" />
</Target>
```

A heads up will be much appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5):

The `.wixproj` is an msbuild file. The `.wxi` is a file handled by the wix compiler. Since msbuild drives the wix compiler, you can use MSbuild properties as wix variables **but not the other way around**. The `<?define>` processing instruction is only seen by the wix compiler, not by MSBuild.

Therefore, I would define `ReleaseCountry` as an [MSBuild property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) instead.